# Firefox addon-sdk: get element of attached panel

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a very simple firefox plugin - developing with addon-sdk. In tutorial, I found a mention of attached-panel to a toggle button, but I can't find a way to and (for example) onclick callback to button in this panel.

This is simplified panel:

```
    <body>
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <input type="button" id="btnInject" value="Inject!">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here's a part of `main.js` file:

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

var { ToggleButton } = require('sdk/ui/button/toggle');
var panels = require("sdk/panel");
var self = require("sdk/self");

var button = ToggleButton({
  id: "my-button",
  label: "my button",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
  },
  onChange: handleChange
});

var panel = panels.Panel({
  contentURL: self.data.url("popup.html"),
  onHide: handleHide
});

function handleChange(state) {
  if (state.checked) {
    panel.show({
      position: button
    });
  }
}

function handleHide() {
  button.state('window', {checked: false});
}
```

I need to assign onclick function, I've tried `panel.getElementById('btnInject').onclick`, but `getElementById` was not found as a function. Also tried a document object, but it wasn`t defined either.

Can anyone help me, how to access this element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have direct access to the DOM of a panel. Instead, you'll need to [attach a small content script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel#contentScriptFile) and emit a message back to `main.js` using the [`panel.port`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel#port) API.

See the [Communicating using port](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port) documentation for further information.

Comment: You're right, I've misunderstood the article, when I read it before